# Alert is not fired or Action Group is not executed. How to investigate?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am baffled! This used to work. I have a very simple Alert that triggers a very simple Action Group. The alert query is:

```
exceptions | where timestamp >= ago(6m) | order by timestamp desc
```

In the App Insights Logs I can see that there are exceptions.

In the Alert screen, in Configure Signal Logic I can see that there are exception. In my mind that means that the Alert should be triggered.

However the Action Group which is just a "Send Email" doesn't seem to be executed since I do not receive the email.

In Monitor Alerts / All Alerts I do not see any alert.

Any idea of how to investigate to see what is going wrong?

Comment: While the root cause of the issue was found, it would be great to see another answer giving steps on "how to investigate".  The answers so far are very specific to the given use case and not applicable to broader issues that might lead people to this question.  E.g., are there logs that can be used to troubleshoot action group failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, the Azure alerting system wasn't working (100%) yesterday!! I left the alerts enabled over night and they starting firing at 3:41 AM PST. Checking the Azure Status website, it doesn't say anything about this.

These were new alerts that I created yesterday. I have other alerts created a while ago and they were firing.

It seems that the new alerts weren't picked up yesterday.

Comment: Encountered absolutely the same issue. Action Group started being executed on the next day only.

Yet not sure whether it's azure alerting service failure or some daily limit we've encountered silently or even some mystic newly created action group limitation.

The most interesting part - fired alerts could be seen in Azure mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some instructions you can follow:

1. make sure you select application insights as target
2. check the time period / frequency / threshold during create alert rule -> add condition:
   For example, if you set the time period as "over last 30 minutes", frequency as "every 5 minutes", threshold as "total number greater than 2".

   Let's assume that this alert will check condition from 2:00 to 2:30(time period), and every 5 minutes(frequency) like from 2:00 - 2:05, if during 2:00-2:05 the total number of exception is more than 2, this will trigger alert, and send you an email.

   If during every 5 minutes, total number of exceptions is less than 2, no alert will be triggered.

Hope it helps.